# my @ symbol and other characters won't work, instead, I get other characters

Tags: keys

I am fairly new to Ubuntu, the first time i ran it of the disk drive, all keys worked fine. However, now @=" M=0 J=1 etc. I can only get a few correct letters. I tried all keyboard and language setting I know of...this is rather annoying!
If you can help me,
thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please tell us your keyboard layout?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me you have your regional settings wrong, a UK keyboard has the @ near the enter key, but a US keyboard has a " near to the enter key on the same key if you get what I mean.

Different regions have different layouts

Answer (score 2):

if you hit <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> all at the same time it alters your keyboard settings.

Just hold all three again and its fixed. (also if other symbols are still wrong try repeating till its back to normal. the quotation marks also switch up)

Answer (score 2):

Its most probably because of your *keyboard layout*. Just change the **keyboard language** (located at `top-right corner` and represented by **En**) from the **English(UK)**  to **English(US)**.

It worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi it seems you are using a uk keymap. 
As @pankaj-sharma has mentioned. Change your keyboard mapping to us;

```
echo "KEYMAP=us" > /etc/vconsole.conf
```

Restart your machine.